# GraphDB Failed to create JVM after attempting to change java options

Tags: jvm, graphdb

Running GraphDB on windows.

I right clicked the icon, clicked settings. Tried to set Xmx512Mb, (so I mistyped, should have been Xmx512M). Now trying to run GraphDB says "Failed to create JVM", even after uninstalling and re installing.

Where can I find and undo what I typed in the settings if the UI is not starting up?

In other words, where is this configuration stored?

I removed AppData/Roaming/GraphDB and AppData/Local/GraphDB Free

Comment: Should be `Xmx512m` -> without the `b` at the end. Also it's usually lowercase `m`

Comment: right I figured that also by now. But the question is how do I undo the wrong setting for graphDB. Its not starting up, so I cannot change it. I need to know where its stored.

Comment: Look for a temp folder named `com.ontotext.graphdb.free` under it, there should be a sub-folder `packager` and in that, a file named `jvmuserargs.cfg` - just edit it by removing the invalid entry at `[JVMUserOverrideOptions]`
Under windows OS, the folder is located in `<USER>\AppData\Roaming`

HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to generalize it, If you set an invalid Java option parameter, GraphDB Free may fail to start after the application restart. The only way to solve this problem is to remove the invalid line from the file:

- %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\com.ontotext.graphdb.free\packager\jvmuserargs.cfg (Windows)
- ~/Library/Application Support/com.ontotext.graphdb.free/packager/jvmuserargs.cfg (Mac OS)
- ~/.local/com.ontotext.graphdb.free/packager/jvmuserargs.cfg (Linux).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Damyan's answer there is a GraphDB Free.cfg file in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\GraphDB Free\app\ which you can edit.